# I get SIGSTOP error when running this program. Why is this?

Tags: binary-search

I was solving a question(code : TWOVRIBL) on codechef cookoff 2019.
Link to the question : https://www.codechef.com/COOK108B/problems/TWOVRIBL

My approach : I tried using Binary Search for finding the P. The goal is to find maximum number of steps taken by X to reach Xf.

-Choose any positive integer P such that P⋅P>Y.
-Change X to P.
-Add P⋅P to Y.

So i figured for maximum answer, i need to select P such that P.P > Y
and P

Plz help! 
//MY CODE :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int find(long y_sqr,long X,long Xf)
{
    int left=X+1,right=1000,mid;
    long num=0,distance_from_X=99990;
    while(left<=right)
    {
        mid=(left+right)/2;
        if(mid*mid<=y_sqr)
        {
            left=mid+1;
        }
        else
        {
            if(mid-X < distance_from_X)
            {
                num=mid;
                distance_from_X=mid-X;
            }
            right=mid-1;

        }
    }
    return num;


}

int main() 
{
    long T;
    cin>>T;
    while(T--)
    {
        long Xf;
        cin>>Xf;
        long X=0,Y=0,P=0,steps=0;
        while(P < Xf)
        {
            P=find(Y,X,Xf);
            if(P*P<=Xf*Xf)
            {
                Y+=P*P;
                X=P;
                steps++;
            }

        }
        if(P!=X)
        {steps++;}
        cout<<steps<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```